# Make cannot acces url before login laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want make cannot acces 'book/input' before login

PassController.php

```
public function authenticate()
    {   
        $data= array('username'=>Input::get('username')'password' =>Input::get('password'));`
        if(Auth::attempt($data)) 
        {
            return Redirect::intended('book/input');
        } 
        else 
        {
            return Redirect::to('/')->with('error', 'Login failed')
        }
```

routes.php

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('book.login');
});

Route::get('book/input',function()
{
    return View::make('book.profile');
});

Route::post('book/auth', 'PassController@authenticate');
```

login.blade.php

```
{{Form::open(array('action' => 'PassController@authenticate')) }}
.....
{{Form::close() }}
```

Login was success, I want just logined user who can access book/input. How to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, concept is called filter, it first check user is logged in,if yes then only allow to that route other wise it will redirect to login page or any page you want, you can specify this in filter.php file.

```
Route::group(['before' => 'auth'], function ()
{
      Route::get('book/input',function()
      {
          return View::make('book.profile');
      });
});
```

for more information about filter go to this link

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-filters

or

http://culttt.com/2013/09/16/use-laravel-4-filters/

Comment: directory structure for view is like view > book > profile right ?